# SSRS chart - remove arrows

Tags: graphics, reporting-services

We are trying to do graph like this:
[image]

The problem is in red circle. We do not want that arrows to be there. But when we turned them off, the numbers will be overlapped. How to solve it? (Like make arrow invisible etc)

Answer (score 6):

You must put the focus on chart series and press F4 to get its properties. Follow the SmartLabels area and change CalloutLineAnchor property to change the arrow and put another simbol or remove all. You can select Disabled property to remove all simbols also.

Comment: It helped me! Thanks!